# Вытащить объект из JSON

Tags: android, json

Я делаю такой запрос getHttpResponse:

```
public void getHttpResponse() throws IOException {
    String url = "https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard?text="
            + word.getText().toString() + "&srcLang=1033&dstLang=1049";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .method("GET", null)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
            Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String mMessage = response.body().string();
            Log.e(TAG, mMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

В переменную String mMessage приходит следующий JSON:

```
{
  "SourceLanguage": 1033,
  "TargetLanguage": 1049,
  "Heading": "word",
  "Translation": {
    "Heading": "word",
    "Translation": "слово",
    "DictionaryName": "LingvoUniversal (En-Ru)",
    "SoundName": "word.wav",
    "Type": 1,
    "OriginalWord": ""
  },
  "SeeAlso": [
    "Word"
  ]
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что каким образом вытащить необходимый объект, например Translation

Comment: вы используете класс модель для обработки ответа? покажите как вы шлете запрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы советовал использовать класс модель. Это облегчит вам жизнь довольно сильно. Для этого ваш json конвертируем в класс используя например такой [сервис_1](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) либо [сервис_2](https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter).

```
public class wordsClass{
 private float SourceLanguage;
 private float TargetLanguage;
 private String Heading;
 Translation TranslationObject;
 ArrayList < Object > SeeAlso = new ArrayList < Object > ();


 // Getter Methods 

 public float getSourceLanguage() {
  return SourceLanguage;
 }

 public float getTargetLanguage() {
  return TargetLanguage;
 }

 public String getHeading() {
  return Heading;
 }

 public Translation getTranslation() {
  return TranslationObject;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setSourceLanguage(float SourceLanguage) {
  this.SourceLanguage = SourceLanguage;
 }

 public void setTargetLanguage(float TargetLanguage) {
  this.TargetLanguage = TargetLanguage;
 }

 public void setHeading(String Heading) {
  this.Heading = Heading;
 }

 public void setTranslation(Translation TranslationObject) {
  this.TranslationObject = TranslationObject;
 }
}
public class Translation {
 private String Heading;
 private String Translation;
 private String DictionaryName;
 private String SoundName;
 private float Type;
 private String OriginalWord;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String getHeading() {
  return Heading;
 }

 public String getTranslation() {
  return Translation;
 }

 public String getDictionaryName() {
  return DictionaryName;
 }

 public String getSoundName() {
  return SoundName;
 }

 public float getType() {
  return Type;
 }

 public String getOriginalWord() {
  return OriginalWord;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setHeading(String Heading) {
  this.Heading = Heading;
 }

 public void setTranslation(String Translation) {
  this.Translation = Translation;
 }

 public void setDictionaryName(String DictionaryName) {
  this.DictionaryName = DictionaryName;
 }

 public void setSoundName(String SoundName) {
  this.SoundName = SoundName;
 }

 public void setType(float Type) {
  this.Type = Type;
 }

 public void setOriginalWord(String OriginalWord) {
  this.OriginalWord = OriginalWord;
 }
}
```

и дальше десериализуем ваш json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
wordsClass wordsClass = gson.fromJson(json, wordsClass.class);
```

Вместо json используйте приходящий к вам json. Ну и дальше уже получить данные из объекта класса будет просто я думаю через обычные геттеры.  [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object) аналогичный вопрос, [туториал_1](https://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html) и еще один [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-data-to-java-object).

### UPDATE

Либо второй вариант, который я считаю более приемлемым. Делаем интерфейсный класс или интерфейс внутри вашей активности:

```
public interface apiInterface{
   @GET("your_url")
   Call<wordsClass> words();
  }
```

шлем запрос:

```
apiInterface service = retrofit.create(apiInterface.class);

       Call<wordsClass> repos = service.listRepos("machadacosta");

       repos.enqueue(new Callback<wordsClass>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<wordsClass> call, Response<wordsClass> response) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("OK"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<wordsClass> call, Throwable t) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("KO"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

       });
```

И теперь ваш ответ это объект класса `wordsClass`. И делать с ним дальше можно что угодно и как угодно. [Вот](https://www.chillcoding.com/android-retrofit-send-http/) пример кода, где расписано все как красиво делать можно и [вот](https://androidclarified.com/retrofit-android-example-http-get-request/) тоже.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы предлагаете не использовать okhttp, а делать через retrofit. Отличные статьи вы привели, но сделав по данному примеру, и указав @SerializedName("текст"), в скобках определение остаётся подчеркнутым

Comment: Разобрался. Оказывается есть такой чудеснейший сайт http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/